# jQuery opposite of "starts with" selector: [^=]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some div tag below:

```
<div class="magazine"></div>
<div class="newsletter"></div> // I need to take this div
<div class="may-moon"></div>
```

If I needed div with class start with "**ma**", I would use `$('div[class^="ma"]')`, but what is opposite? thanks.

Comment: Opposite as in "doesn't start with" or "ends with"?

Comment: Does opposite mean, does not start with "ma"?  Or do you want endswith instead of startswith?

Comment: not selector, learn about it.

Comment: Doesn't start with...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The opposite would be to use [jQuery :not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
$('div:not([class^="ma"])')
```

Comment: Or, alternatively, use [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/): `$('div').not('[class^="ma"]')`.

Comment: Except that `:not` is faster : http://jsperf.com/not-vs-not32 (tested with chrome, it is maybe a false statement for other broswer)

Comment: @Karl-André Gagnon: http://jsperf.com/not-vs-not32/2 - it's a typo in `.not()` argument. Doesn't change results though

Comment: Faster in Firefox too. IE 8 was... inconclusive.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the negative filtering function "[not](http://api.jquery.com/not/)" like this: `$('div').not('[class^="ma"]')`, or the negative selector "[:not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)" like this: `$('div:not([class^="ma"])')` (as pointed by [Karl-André Gagnon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2324107/karl-andre-gagnon))

Comment: It's not a selector, but a filtering function. Selector is `:not()`

Comment: @DanielGimenez Some friendly advice: Please do not lecture users on how to answer. More specifically telling them to delete the answer. We indicate usefulness or un-usefulness of posts by downvotes, if you think it's a copy - you can flag it. A lot of users consider a comment like the one you just left rude.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum thanks for the advice.  The answer has changed from the original, but it was pretty much the same answer just given two minutes after.  Seemed cheap.  I was trying to give jackmno a chance to delete it before I downvoted in case it was accidental.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `:not() Selector` for this. because there is no exact opposite selector exist of `[^=]` and `*` in jquery.

```
:not() Selector - Selects all elements that do not match the given selector.
```

[See more about Jquery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

There a opposite selector exist `!` -

```
Attribute Not Equal Selector [name!="value"] - Select elements that either don’t have the specified attribute, or do have the specified attribute but not with a certain value.
```

but use of this `!` selector, you need to provide full-name of class.

```
$('div[class!="magazine"][class!="may-moon"]')
```

[Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/ZUxT5/)